# How to get category list in select box option

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add options in my control like `key => value` pair array of all available options

Like this:

```
$this->add_control('show_elements', [
    'label' => __('Show Elements', 'your-plugin'),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
    'options' => [
        'title' => __('Title', 'your-plugin'),
        'description' => __('Description', 'your-plugin'),
        'button' => __('Button', 'your-plugin'),
    ],
    'multiple' => true,
        ]
);
```

But in place of title description and button I want to have all the categories of my post so I write a function `my_cat`

```
function my_cat() {
    $categories = get_categories();
    echo '[';
    foreach ($categories as $category) :

        echo $category->term_id . '=>' . $category->name . ',';

    endforeach;
    echo ']';
}
```

And I use it for options

```
$this->add_control('show_elements', [
    'label' => __('Show Elements', 'your-plugin'),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
    'options' => my_cat(),
    'multiple' => true,
        ]
);
```

But I'm not getting option with category list, is there anything wrong with `my_cat` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by replacing you `my_cat()` with this:

```
function my_cat() {
    $categories = get_categories();
    $cat_array = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) :
        $cat_array[$category->term_id] = $category->name;
    endforeach;
    return $cat_array;
}
```

To do this correctly, in opinion, we want `choices` to take associative array in this form:

```
$this->add_control('show_elements', [
    'label' => __('Show Elements', 'your-plugin'),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
    'choices' => my_cat(), //<-- Check this line.
    'multiple' => true,
        ]
);
```

Reference: [add control](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control)

Hope this helps!

Comment: helps a lot :-D

Comment: @Raunak Gupta Is there a way to add all. I mean with this code I had each categories Is there a way to add all with each categories so we can add all categories or the selected one