# Wordpress Metabox populate select from array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to populate a select with the registered users (contributors) from an array to use it in the frontend, but for some reason I can't get it done.
Here's my code:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('role' => 'Contributor'));

if (!empty($user_query->results))
{
    $index = 0;
    $contributors = array();
    foreach ($user_query->results as $user)
    {
        $contributors[$index] = $user->ID;
        $index++;
    }
}

array(
    'name' => esc_html__('Select', 'your-prefix'),
    'id' => "{$prefix}tecnico",
    'type' => 'select',
    // Array of 'value' => 'Label' pairs for select box
    'options' => $contributors,
    // Select multiple values, optional. Default is false.
    'multiple' => false,
    'std' => 'value2',
    'placeholder' => esc_html__('Select an Item', 'your-prefix'),
),
```

Comment: Query and creating the array `$contributors` seems correct. I think the problem is in the second part which i am not sure what's the use of it. Firstly, you could add an `print_r($contributors);` to be sure it holds the desirable data. Do you have any errors? Why it starts with `array(..),` ?

Comment: Hi, the print_r looks correct: Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 ) I only need the users ID, so it works fine. It starts with an array because is part of a Multidimensional array with other metaboxes..

Comment: try by replacing `options` with `choices` or you can my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41651559/5019802)